# Two DIVS keep distance when overlaps each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css-transitions, uc-browser

I have two DIVS which html code is given

```js
function collision($div1, $div2) {
 var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
 var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
 var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
 var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
 var b1 = y1 + h1;
 var r1 = x1 + w1;
 var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
 var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
 var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
 var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
 var b2 = y2 + h2;
 var r2 = x2 + w2;

 if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
 return true;
}

window.setInterval(function () {
 $('#result').text(collision($('#div1'), $('#div2')));
 if (collision($('#div1'), $('#div2')) == true) {
  $('#div1').addClass('touch');
  $('#div2').addClass('touch');
  $('#div1,#div2').css();
 }
 if (collision($('#div1'), $('#div2')) == false) {
  $('#div2').addClass("remTouch");
  $('#div1').addClass('remTouch');
 }
}, 200);

$('#div1').draggable();
```

```css
.touch{
    margin:20px;
    transition: margin 1s;
}
.remTouch{
    margin:-20x;
    transition: margin 1s;
}
#div1 { 
    width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: pink;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#div2 { 
    width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="div1"></div>
<br/>
<div id="div2"></div>
    
<p>Colliding? <span id="result">false</span>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now the problem is that when i move the small div towards the bigger one, after overlapping it moves but while during false condition nothing happens, I mean when condition is false i want to move the bigger div back to its position. More specifically i want the bigger div to run away smoothly from the smaller div and keep a little distance. I want to do it just like UC browser has done it. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This code is very greedy and can be heavily optimized. Right now, every 200ms, you make a whole bunch of DOM requests and create an awful lot of jQuery objects. By caching your elements (`const $div1 = $('#div1')`) and reusing them (`$div1.addClass("...")`) you will hugely relieve the CPU.

Comment: sure that's a problem but if you know any solution to the specific problem to create the same sided magnetic effect just like UC Browser

Comment: No I don't, but this magnetic thing sound _much_ more difficult to achieve than just optimizing your current code and make it performant.

Comment: On true you can calculate the desired new position using current position of divs and view port boundaries for second div and set the css top and left properties. EX. $('#div2').draggable();
      $('#div2').css('top', 200);
       $('#div2').css('left', 200);

Comment: have created a fiddle, @JalalAhmad you can modify the top and left based on your requirement. https://jsfiddle.net/uv4uurzn/

Comment: @gusaindpk so nice of you but you can notice it changes its position once, the second time it doesn't move and needs a page refresh to work for the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/uv4uurzn/3/
JS change:

```
  var newTop =  $('#div1').offset().top + 150;
  var newLeft =  $('#div1').offset().left + 10;
  console.log(newTop);
  $('#div2').css('top', newTop);
  $('#div2').css('left', newLeft);
```

CSS update:`#div2 { 
      width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; 
      position: fixed;
      top: 150px;
      left: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
    }`

you can set div to fixed position and set top left as per your desire.

Comment: @JalalAhmad you can accept the ans if it works for u :)

Comment: that's nice dude, bundles of thanks :) God bless you